# Rotate logfiles each time the application is started (Python)

Tags: python, logging, rotation

I'm using the logging module in Python and I would like it to create a new logfile each time my application is started. The older logfiles shoud be rotated (eg: logfile.txt -> logfile1.txt, etc).

I already found this:

http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

> BaseRotatingHandler is the base class
>   for handlers that rotate log files at
>   a certain point. It is not meant to be
>   instantiated directly. Instead, use
>   RotatingFileHandler or
>   TimedRotatingFileHandler.

The RotatingFileHandler does a rollover at a predetermined size and the TimedRotatingFileHandler does a rollover based on the product of when and interval. Both are not what I want, I want the rotation to happen immediately when my application starts.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I might be enough to use `RotatingFileHandler` without `maxBytes`, then call `doRollover()` on application start.

Yup, seems to work fine. The code below will create a new log file on each application run, with added timestamps for log start and close times. Running it will print the list of available log files. You can inspect them to check correct behavior. Adapted from the Python docs example:

```
import os
import glob
import logging
import logging.handlers
import time

LOG_FILENAME = 'logging_rotatingfile_example.out'

# Set up a specific logger with our desired output level
my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Check if log exists and should therefore be rolled
needRoll = os.path.isfile(LOG_FILENAME)

# Add the log message handler to the logger
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILENAME, backupCount=50)

my_logger.addHandler(handler)

# This is a stale log, so roll it
if needRoll:    
    # Add timestamp
    my_logger.debug('\n---------\nLog closed on %s.\n---------\n' % time.asctime())

    # Roll over on application start
    my_logger.handlers[0].doRollover()

# Add timestamp
my_logger.debug('\n---------\nLog started on %s.\n---------\n' % time.asctime())

# Log some messages
for i in xrange(20):
    my_logger.debug('i = %d' % i)

# See what files are created
logfiles = glob.glob('%s*' % LOG_FILENAME)

print '\n'.join(logfiles)
```

Comment: +1 For practical solution.  Unfortunately, this solution requires knowing which order handlers have been added -- i.e. my_logger.handlers[0] vs my_logger.handlers[n].  Is there an elegant way to avoid avoid hard-coding that value?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could just call handler.doRollover(). In other words, maintain a reference to it somewhere.

Comment: @JS. should be very simple: handler is already initiated, so you should just call
`handler.doRollover()`
another way would be to search for a handler of a expected type, like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427107/identify-python-logging-handler-type

Answer (score 7):

Simplest way is just to have a date tag in log file name, so when you start app each time you will get a new log file.

e.g.

```
dateTag = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%b-%d_%H-%M-%S")
logging.basicConfig(filename="myapp_%s.log" % dateTag, level=logging.DEBUG)
```

so each time you will have log like `myapp_2011-Jan-11_12-27-29.log`

Another benefit is that you can mix this with RotatingFileHandler to have separate log for each app invocation, where each log itself is further divided into multiple fixed size logs.

Comment: Is there a way to timestamp the log file in the logging.conf file?

Comment: Has anyone tried this? In my case, the file is created only for the first run and for subsequent runs, the same file is picked up and appended to.

Comment: @krypto07 I have, using FileHandler directly, works flawlessly. `handler = FileHandler('io-%s.log' % dateTag)`

Answer (score 2):

Log Rotation and RoatatingFileHandler are usually designed and desirable when the application is running for a very long time (days) and you want the log to keep rotation. Under cases where I have to rotate the log upon restart of the application, I had to do that outside of the Logfile handler, which was easier. It was like, before the log writer call for the first time, I would see if the log file already existed, and if yes, rename it and create a new log file. The renaming should be differentiated from the handler's renaming mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement to be able to force a log rotation at startup based on a command-line option, but for the logfiles to otherwise rotate on their regular schedule. This was my solution:

```
import logging

from logging.handlers import BaseRotatingHandler
from typing import Union

def rotate_logs(loggers: Union[str,list]=None, delimiter: str=','):
    """Rotate logs.

    Args:
        loggers: List of logger names as list object or as string,
            separated by `delimiter`.

        delimiter: Separator for logger names, if `loggers` is :obj:`str`.
            Defaults to ``,`` (comma).

    """

    # Convert loggers to list.
    if isinstance(loggers, str):
        loggers = [t.strip() for t in loggers.split(delimiter)]

    handlers = []
    root = logging.getLogger()

    # Include root logger in dict.    
    ld = {'': root, **root.manager.loggerDict}

    for k, v in ld.items():
        if loggers is not None and k not in loggers:
            continue

        try:
            for h in v.handlers:
                if (isinstance(h, BaseRotatingHandler) and
                    h not in handlers):

                    handlers.append(h)

        except AttributeError:
            pass

    for h in handlers:
        h.doRollover()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

**Notes:**

- This has been validated to work if `maxBytes > 0` on a `RotatingFileHandler`.
- This method hasn't been tested with a `TimedRotatingFileHandler`, but should work.
- This method eliminates the need to maintain a reference to the `RotatingFileHandler` to be rotated; as a result, it can easily be used when configuring logging using `logging.config`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Senthil Kumaran stated, this kind of logic is best put at the application level. Here's a full working example that sets up a logger that prints to stdout and writes to file. At application start up, if an existing log is found with the same name, it will be rotated out of the way in to a directory named 'old'. The RotatingFileHandler then handles rotating live logs when their size exceeds 512 bytes.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers as handlers
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List


def configure_logger():
    file_handler = _get_file_handler()
    log_handlers: List[logging.Handler] = [logging.StreamHandler(), file_handler]
    logging.basicConfig(
        level="INFO",
        format="[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(name)s]: %(message)s",
        handlers=log_handlers,
    )


def _get_file_handler() -> handlers.RotatingFileHandler:
    log_path_str = "logs/my_app.log"
    log_path = Path(log_path_str)
    _rotate_existing_log(log_path)
    log_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    return handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
        log_path,
        maxBytes=512,
        backupCount=5,
        # don't append to existing file, instead create a new
        mode="w",
    )


def _rotate_existing_log(log_path: Path):
    """
    If log file already exists, rotate it out of the way into an 'old' directory
    :param log_path:
    :return:
    """
    if log_path.exists():
        old_log_paths = log_path.parent / "old"
        old_log_paths.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        i = 1
        old_log_name = old_log_paths / (log_path.name + f".{i}")
        while old_log_name.exists():
            i += 1
            old_log_name = old_log_paths / (log_path.name + f".{i}")
        log_path.rename(old_log_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    configure_logger()
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("hello world")
```

The effect of running this on my system a few times gave the following directory and file structure:

```
C:\USERS\PYCHARMPROJECTS\SCRATCH\LOGS
|   my_app.log
|
\---old
        my_app.log.1
        my_app.log.2
        my_app.log.3
        my_app.log.4
```

[image: log rotate file structure]