# Identify python logging handler type

Tags: python, logging

I would like to change python logging file on the fly. I could do that by removing the existing handler and then adding a new one:

```
for hdlr in log.handlers:  # remove all old handlers
    log.removeHandler(hdlr)
log.addHandler(fileh)
```

However, if my logger has multiple handlers, like stream handler, rotating file handler, , I would like to remove

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the we could find the class of the file stream to remove selective handlers:

```
for handler in logger:
  if handler.__class__.__name__ == 'FileHandler':
    logger.removeHandler(handler)
```

Answer (score 1):

logger is not iterable. It has to be logger.handlers.

```
for handler in logger.handlers:
    if handler.__class__.__name__ == 'FileHandler':
    logger.removeHandler(handler)
```