# New Logfile Creation when python script starts executing

Tags: logging, python-3.5

I'm using the logging module in Python and I would like it to create a new logfile each time when i start executing Python script.
Example: 1st time execution--new.log
         2nd time execution--new1.log
I dont want to append data to a single file rather i would like to create a new  log file for every execution and insert data into it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are looking for something similar to this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654915/rotate-logfiles-each-time-the-application-is-started-python

Comment: Yes but it is not creating new log file for every execution infact it is appending the data to an existing file