# Why RotatingFileHandler is appending to old file?

Tags: python, logging

I have a nice logging setup where I create detailed debugging logs to a file, while displaying clean info logging to stdout. I wanted to get Rotating logs in the mix, so I checked out this advice: [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654915/rotate-logfiles-each-time-the-application-is-started-python), (which is exactly what I want). Problem is, I'm having a similar problem as [other stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278309/python-rotatingfilehandler-writing-to-non-base-file). Can anyone answer why after my code calls for 'doRollover()', the logs are still being written to logtest.log.1?

```
#logtest
import sys, os, time, logging, logging.handlers

log_file = r'/logs/test/logtest.log'

needRoll = os.path.isfile(log_file)
rotater=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_file, backupCount=5)

log = logging.getLogger()
logging.basicConfig(
    filename=log_file,
    level='DEBUG',
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    handlers=[rotater])
stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.addHandler(stdout_handler)

if needRoll:
    log.debug("Log closed on %s." %time.asctime())
    rotater.doRollover()

log.info('New Log!')
```

Results:

logtest.log = {Empty}

logtest.log.1 = 
2019-02-25 14:15:01,372 - root - DEBUG - Log closed on Mon Feb 25 14:15:01 2019.

2019-02-25 14:15:01,381 - root - INFO - New Log!

Edit: Fix guided by John Anderson:

```
log_file = r'/logs/test/logtest.log'
needRoll = os.path.isfile(log_file)

log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

rotater=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_file, backupCount=5)
rotater.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
rotater.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"))
log.addHandler(rotater)

stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.addHandler(stdout_handler)

if needRoll:
    log.debug("Log closed for next run on %s." %time.asctime())
    rotater.doRollover()

log.info('New Log!')
```

Comment: When I try to run your code, I get `ValueError: 'stream' or 'filename' should not be specified together with 'handlers'`.

Comment: After removing the `filename=log_file,` line and removing the leading `/` in `log_file = r'/logs/test/logtest.log'`, your code works as expected for me on Python 3.6.7 on Ubuntu 18.04. What version of `Python` are you using and what is your `OS`?

Comment: Thanks to John Anderson for pointing me to filename=log_file. I am using python 2.7 in a linux docker container. I rewrote the logger configuration without using logging.basicConfig() and got the intended results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Anderson pointed me in the right direction by showing me that setting the filename in the basicConfig() function might be causing the problem. I rewrote the logging without it and it works fine.

```
log_file = r'/logs/test/logtest.log'
needRoll = os.path.isfile(log_file)

log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

rotater=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_file, backupCount=5)
rotater.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
rotater.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"))
log.addHandler(rotater)

stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.addHandler(stdout_handler)

if needRoll:
    log.debug("Log closed for next run on %s." %time.asctime())
    rotater.doRollover()

log.info('New Log!')
```