# Create a new log file each time in python

Tags: python, logging

I am completely new to Python and this query may sound too basic.

I want a new log file to be created each time the application is run.

I got my requirement done using the code below.

```
def initializeLog(logSpec):

    dirName   = logSpec['dirName']
    fileName  = logSpec['fileName']
    timeStamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    logFQ     = dirName + fileName + "_" + timeStamp + ".log"

    if not os.path.exists(dirName):
        os.makedirs(dirName)

    logFormat = '%(asctime)s %(funcName)-25s  %(levelname)-7s : %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(
        level    = logging.INFO,
        format   = logFormat,
        fileName = logFQ,
        filemode = 'w'
    )
```

I know this is far from ideal.It would be great if I can get some pointers as to how best achieve it.
I have checked WatchedFileHandler, RotatingFileHandler but couldn't get them to work to suit my req.

Please advice.

Comment: A simple suggestion to include date in file_name at the time of creating the log file. More granular log file name can include timestamp.

Comment: Another example to use https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler

Comment: This addresses the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654915/rotate-logfiles-each-time-the-application-is-started-python and is kind of proof that it's rather random whether you get an RTFM response or a useful one

Answer (score -1):

You should take some time to look through the Python logging documentation:

[Logging: How-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html)

In summary, you can create a logger and configure it to report at different levels, and also configure it to create new log files each time, plus output to console, or new files per day ... lots of options here.

```
import logging

# set up logging to file - see previous section for more details 

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename='/temp/myapp.log',
                    filemode='w')
```

Comment: The filename should changes every boot.

Comment: Then they can provide whatever file name in their basic config. Its an example from the documentation. Not a solution