# Is there a way to force RotatingFileHandler to rotate to the next file?

Tags: python

This question is regarding Python logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler object.
The RotatingFileHandler object rotates a file after it fills upto maxBytes(if specified). But wondering if there is a way to force rotation before the log file is filled up.
The reason for this is that the test script likes to rotate log files after every iteration of a test case.

Comment: can you include more information, such as a sample of the test case code?

Comment: What is the timing or criteria for when to force the rotation? There is a solution here that forces rotation on each application start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654915/rotate-logfiles-each-time-the-application-is-started-python. Maybe you can adapt it on your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`doRollover()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler.doRollover) will do an immediate rollover.

Comment: this is the correct answer; `.rotate()` is eventually called by `.doRollover()` (and not useful by itself without a source and destination)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call `.rotate()` on the log handler to force rotation

docs
https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.BaseRotatingHandler.rotate